# SQLAlchemy keeps the DB connection open

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I have an issue with in my Flask app concerning SQLAlchemy and MySQL.
In one of my file: `connection.py` I have a function that creates a DB connection and set it as a global variable:

```py
db = None
def db_connect(force=False):
   global db
   db = pymysql.connect(.....)

def makecursor():
    cursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    return db, cursor
```

And then I have a **User** Model created with SQL ALchemy `models.ppy`

```py
class User(Model):
    id = column........
```

It inherits from Model which is a class that I create in another file `orm.py`

```py
import connection

Engine = create_engine(url, creator=lambda x: connection.makecursor()[0], pool_pre_ping=True)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=Engine, autoflush=autoflush)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

class _Model:
    query = Session.query_property()
    Model = declarative_base(cls=_Model, constructor=model_constructor)
```

In my application I can have long script running so the DB timeout. So I have a function that "reconnect" my DB (it actually only create a new connexion and replace the global DB variable)

My goal is to be able to catch the close of my DB and reconnect it instantly. I tried with SQLAlchemy events but it never worked. ([here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.close))

Here is some line that reproduces the error:

```py
res = User.query.filter_by(username="myuser@gmail.com").first()
connection.db.close()
# connection.reconnect() # --> SOLUTION
res = User.query.filter_by(username="myuser@gmail.com").first()
```

If you guys have any ideas of how to achieve that, let me know 
Oh and I forgot, this application is still running with `python2.7`.